# How to get the total amount of discounts applied to a cart

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying find out how I can get the total discounts that have been
applied to a shopping cart in Hybris 6.4.

For example one may product may have a 10% and another 20%, if these have been added to the cart how can I find out what the total amount discounts in the full cart is.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Be sure to follow these guidelines (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable) while posting any questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You can find it as Total Discounts(`cart.getTotalDiscounts()`) in hmc/backoffice.

To know more how totalDiscounts being calculated, debug DefaultCalculationService.